# How to create element with class name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create element with class name using javascript ?

i tried to create element like this

```
<div class ="dialog_red_top_page">
    <div class ="inner_dialog_red_top_page">
        <p class="dialog_red_top_page_text">
            test
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

by using javascript but not work , how can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/n5phf/186/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){        
    $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        var div = $('<div class ='dialog_red_top_page'><div class ='inner_dialog_red_top_page'><p class='dialog_red_top_page_text'>test</p></div></div>');    
        div.html("test");
        div.appendTo('#wrapper');

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the problem with quotes  use " around class instead of single one

Comment: it's show only `<div class="dialog_red_top_page">test</div>`

Comment: In the example you have given, the problem is the quotes within your variable. You should use double quotes around the entire variable "string" (in this case the html code) and single quotes for the class names.

Comment: update your script like this:  $('#myBtn').click(function(){
    $("<div class ='dialog_red_top_page'><div class ='inner_dialog_red_top_page'><p class='dialog_red_top_page_text'>test</p> </div></div>").appendTo('#wrapper');
    
});

Comment: [like this Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aitnasser/kcbLo0gr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st : the problem with quotes use " around class instead of single one

2nd : with `div.html("test");` you change the div html to `<div>test</div>`

you can use .html() for wrapper

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    var div = $('<div class ="dialog_red_top_page"><div class ="inner_dialog_red_top_page"><p class="dialog_red_top_page_text"">test</p></div></div>');    
    $('#wrapper').html(div);
    // you can try .append instead of .html()  just give it a try
    //$('#wrapper').append(div);
    //$(div).appendTo('#wrapper');

});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/n5phf/188/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the classes name by `"` instead of `'` and  remove `div.html("test");`. It says replace html of selected element by `test` it means it removes `.inner_dialog_red_top_page` and replace it by `test`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/n5phf/190/)

Comment: it's show only `<div class="dialog_red_top_page">test</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are all singel quotes

Do it like this

```
var div = $('<div class="dialog_red_top_page">'
  + '<div class="inner_dialog_red_top_page">'
  + '<p class="dialog_red_top_page_text">test</p>'
  + '</div></div>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape all ' characters with a \':

```
var div = $('<div class =\'dialog_red_top_page\'><div class =\'inner_dialog_red_top_page\'><p class=\'dialog_red_top_page_text\'>test</p></div></div>');
```

What your code actually does is: creates a div with div and paragraph inside, but then you call:

```
div.html("test");
```

which overrides content of .dialog_red_top_page div.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hf0m1c18/)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
        $("<div class ='dialog_red_top_page'><div class ='inner_dialog_red_top_page'><p class='dialog_red_top_page_text'>test</p> </div></div>").appendTo('#wrapper');

    });
```